# Is a surjective homomorphism $f: A\to A $ where $A$ is Noetherian an isomorphism? Is it true for injective homomorphism?

Tags: ring-theory, noetherian, ring-isomorphism

I am confused as to how to approach this. So I know the answer is it is isomorphism for a surjective homomorphism but not for an injective homomorphism.

For surjective homomorphism, I used the fact that $A \cong A/\ker f$. Since $f$ is surjective, I think that $\ker f = 0$ but why exactly I am not sure. Also I have not used the Noetherian condition so far. So if I start from assuming $\ker f$ as an ideal, we know that $\ker f \subset I$ where I is some ideal of ring $A$ because of the Noetherian condition.

As for the injective mapping $f$, we can definitely say that $f(r_1)=f(r_2)\implies r_1=r_2$. Therefore, there can not be more than one element in $\ker f$ so this should have been an isomorphism but the test marked this as wrong which means my conclusion that $\ker f = 0$ is incorrect but I can't see why. I don't even know where the Noetherian condition plays a role in this.

Comment: They're both definitely false without the Noetherian hypothesis; take $A = k[x_1, x_2, \dots ]$ to be a polynomial ring in countably many variables and consider 1) the surjection given by $x_1 \mapsto 0$ and $x_i \mapsto x_{i-1}, i \ge 2$, or 2) the injection given by $x_i \mapsto x_{i+1}$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan How are guys here able to think of these examples right away? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I've just used it before. It's a simple example that occurs a lot in problems like this. The same idea can be used to construct a surjection resp. an injection from an infinite-dimensional vector space to itself which is not a bijection.

Comment: There are certainly endomorphisms $f:A \to A$ for Noetherian rings $A$ which are injective but not isomorphisms. For instance, try the map $f:\mathbb{F}_p[[t]] \to \mathbb{F}_p[[t]]$ given by $t \mapsto t^p$ a try. Note that for $f$ to be an isomorphism it has to be both injective and surjective. Now what is in the preimage of $t$?